# Can "ng serve" be configured to use swap space if there is not enough memory?

Tags: memory, windows-10, angular-cli, oom

I'm trying to build an Angular 13 project in GitBash on Windows 10.  Although I'm setting

```
$ export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
```

When I attempt to start my application, it immediately exits

```
$ ng serve

<--- Last few GCs --->


<--- JS stacktrace --->


#
# Fatal javascript OOM in GC during deserialization
```

I do not have that much more memory on my machine and I suspect Angular isn't really complaining about memory anyway since the process exits so quickly.  Any way to configure the app to use swap space ona  windows machine?

Comment: Do you have 32bit or 64bit version of nodejs installed?

Comment: It is a 64-bit installation (Windows 10 OS)